# In Spring Cloud gateway API, how add dynamic headers or query parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on application in which I am using Spring Cloud gateway and in front-end Angular 2, for login I am using Keyclock SSO.

However, after getting logged in I need to send some user information in front-end in some encrypted format, either via headers or query parameters. For that in Spring Cloud gateway I have written below code but it's not working.

This is my custom GlobalFilter where I try to add it headers and parameters but in front-end I am not getting it.

```
@Component
public class InterceptorFilterGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<InterceptorFilterGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {


    public InterceptorFilterGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Config newConfig() {
        return new Config();
    }

    public static class Config {
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest sr = exchange.getRequest();
            Mono var10000 = exchange.getPrincipal().filter((principal) -> principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken)
                    .map(p -> p).map((p) -> {
                        LinkedHashSet<URI> attr = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ORIGINAL_REQUEST_URL_ATTR);
                        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

                      // Here I try to add query parameter

                        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                        queryParams.put("e", Collections.singletonList(toHexString(ja.toString().getBytes())));
                      
                        URI newUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(request.getURI())
                                .replaceQueryParams(unmodifiableMultiValueMap(queryParams))
                                .build(true).toUri();
                        
                        ServerHttpRequest updatedRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().uri(newUri)
                                .build();
                       // Here I add header
                        updatedRequest.mutate().header("e", toHexString(ja.toString().getBytes())).build();


                        return exchange.mutate().request(updatedRequest).build();

            }).defaultIfEmpty(exchange).flatMap(chain::filter);

}

        return var10000;
    };
}
```

And in application yml file I am providing route as follow:

```
- id: appDepartmentWise
          predicates:
            - Path=/app/*/sso_login
            - Method=GET,POST
          uri: http://localhost:9000/app/
          filters:
            - PreserveHostHeader
            - RewritePath=/.*, /app/index.html
            - InterceptorFilter
            - AddRequestParameter=e,*
```

What configuration is missing, and how to add dynamic Header or Query Parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In case if it helps any one to add dynamic query parameter and redirect page you can do it using below code:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public Mono<Void> sendRedirect(ServerWebExchange exchange, Principal p) {

       // Here we can can create string which can have dynamic parameters
       String responseData = "e="+p..getName();

       return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
           ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
           response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);

        // this used to get the base URL.

           UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI()).replacePath(exchange.getRequest().getPath().contextPath().value()).replaceQuery((String)null).fragment((String)null).build();

// As below we can re-generate the URL and redirect it.
           response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create(uriComponents.toUriString()+"/app/Dept"+"/sso_login?"+responseData));
       });
   }
```